# Gurobi Python Error: list index out of range

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin, gurobi

Working with Gurobi in Zeppelin (oracle data studio) and I keep getting a list index error. Here is the code and the error message. New to Gurobi, ill really appreciate any helpful input on how to solve this.

The error seems to appear while adding the variable (quantity) to the model (deal)

```
%python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import *
from rsecommon.analytics.gurobi import *
try:

    instance = rseenv.RseGurobiEnv.getInstance()
    env = instance.getGurobiEnv()
    # Model
    deal = Model("Deal Optimization", env)
    
    # Parameters
    items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9', 'item10']
    volumes = {'item1':1, 'item2':1, 'item3':2, 'item4':2, 'item5':3, 'item6':3, 'item7':4, 'item8':4, 'item9':5, 'item10':5}
    discounts = {'item1':0.05, 'item2':0.04, 'item3':0.01, 'item4':0.08, 'item5':0.06, 'item6':0.02, 'item7':0.01, 'item8':0.09, 'item9':0.06, 'item10':0.09}
    min_qty = {'item1':540, 'item2':70, 'item3':220, 'item4':170, 'item5':60, 'item6':850, 'item7':910, 'item8':310, 'item9':480, 'item10':60}

    capacity_cap = 5000

    # Variables
    quantity = deal.addVars(items, ub = (5000/volumes[item] for item in volumes),name='quantity')
    
    # Constraints
    deal.addConstr(((gp.quicksum(volumes[item]*quantity[item] for item in volumes) <= capacity_cap )), "Capacity")

    # Set objective
    deal.setObjective(quantity.prod(discounts), GRB.MAXIMIZE) 

    # Optimize
    deal.optimize()

    for v in deal.getVars():
        print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))

    print('Obj: %g' % deal.objVal)

except GurobiError as e:
    print('Error code ' + str(e.errno) + ": " + str(e.message))

except AttributeError:
    print('Enco111untered an attribute error')
```

**Error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-2988405025033753797.py", line 312, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in <module>
  File "model.pxi", line 2496, in gurobipy.Model.addVars
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-2988405025033753797.py", line 319, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-2988405025033753797.py", line 312, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in <module>
  File "model.pxi", line 2496, in gurobipy.Model.addVars
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a dictionary for the UB values in the call to Model.addVars:

```
quantity = deal.addVars(items,
                        ub = {item:5000/volumes[item] for item in items},
                        name='quantity')
```

Comment: Now I am trying to print the results as a data frame and i am getting a KeyError: 0 due to the 4th line

here is the code

`deal_quantity = pd.DataFrame(columns=["items", "quantitys"])

for item in items:
    if quantity[item].x > 1e-6:
        deal_quantity = deal_quantity.append({"items": quantity[0], "quantitys": quantity[item].x}, ignore_index=True)  
deal_quantity.index=[''] * len(deal_quantity)
deal_quantity`

Comment: KeyError: 0 suggests an issue with `quantity[0]` in your code.